# Understanding the characteristics of a MOSFET as a switch

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, level-shifting, logic-level

**Edit 4:**
Thanks to the feedback in the comments I tested again and realized that the problem I describe below, with the output voltage being too low, happens regardless of whether the external device is connected or not! (I must have made a mistake in my previous testing, sorry!) So apparently I am not understanding the [TN2106N3-G](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TN2106-N-Channel-Enhancement-Mode-Vertical-DMOS-FET-Data-Sheet-20005942A.pdf) correctly - I thought I was operating in the saturation region but I guess I am not? Could someone help clarify what I missed? And perhaps even suggest a better replacement for the ZVN4424A?
**/Edit 4**

I am trying to drive a logic input of a proprietary 5V device for which the manufacturer gives almost no specifications, except that it outputs at 5V and requires a minimum input of 3.3V (but because the specifications are so limited I don't really trust them and I would like to give the device 5V). Its logic levels are also inverted relative to the UART of the Arduino MKR I am trying to connect to it, so I built a simple inverting level shifter using an N-MOSFET:

[image: MOSFET circuit]

By "Works" I mean the output to the device is 0-5V as expected:

[image: Oscilloscope plot]

By "Doesn't Work" I mean the output to the device maxes out at about 2.5V:

[image: Oscilloscope plot]

The reason I chose the 5.1k resistor instead of 1k is to save a bit of current (this is a battery-operated device) and I didn't think 5mA vs. 1mA would make a difference to the circuit. The reason I used the [Microchip TN2106N3-G](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TN2106-N-Channel-Enhancement-Mode-Vertical-DMOS-FET-Data-Sheet-20005942A.pdf) instead of the [Diodes Inc ZVN4424A](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZVN4424A.pdf) is because the latter had shipping problems at the time, plus the former is half the price.

I don't often use MOSFETs like this so my questions are:

1. Did I make some stupid mistake when choosing TN2106N3-G or changing the resistor, is there something simple I am overlooking?
2. Could this have something to do with the input characteristics of the proprietary device? **Edit 4:** It doesn't!

**Edit:** On the advice of TonyM in the comments, I measured the voltage at the input port when pulled up to 5V and pulled down to GND for different resistor values:

| R | act. | 5.082V | GND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 220 | 218.8Ω | 5.071V | 0V |
| 1k | 996Ω | 5.032V | 0V |
| 5.1k | 5.103kΩ | 4.833V | 0V |
| 10k | 9.98kΩ | 4.617V | 0V |
| 22k | 21.9kΩ | 4.163V | 0V |

A linear fit gives: V = 5.06261 - 0.0000418099 * R  (R²=0.99682)

On the advice of tobalt in the comments, measuring the resistance of the input to ground on my multimeter shows 100kΩ. Using the diode measuring function shows 0.744V from ground to the input.

I also should have mentioned before that this input port is bidirectional but configured for input.

**Edit 2:** So the measurements appear to confirm that there is a 100kΩ pulldown on the input. However, a simple voltage divider doesn't explain the observed measurements, so now I am back to wondering if either there is something about the MOSFET I am not understanding, or there is something else about the input that is causing this.

**Edit 3:** Reducing the 5.1kOhm resistor down to 1kOhm in the circuit with the TN2106N3-G increases the peak-to-peak voltage of the signal to about 4.3V. Better, but still not the same as the ZVN4424A...

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. You could start by profiling the current sink and source of the unknown input. In turn, connect a 220R then 1K then 5K1 then 10K resistor to the input, first as pull-ups to 5 V then as pull-downs to GND. Measure the voltage at the input each time then edit the results into your question. You can use a bit different resistor values to these.

Comment: that input might have a 4k7 pulldown resistor. you can check with a multimeter

Comment: @tobalt, unfortunately a multimeter won't be able to detect active circuitry draw (e.g. diodes in the path) and needs the power off, so can be affected by parallel loads. I've found that in the past. Using resistors solves all that and is quick and easy.

Comment: @TonyM agreed in principle. But for an input there is not much active circuitry in the way apart from potential clamping diodes. So a pulldown resistance will measure accurately.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks! I found my old resistor kit and updated the question.

Comment: @tobalt Thanks! I updated the question.

Comment: Wow, who chose the colors for that user interface?

Comment: @pipe It's a DS212 Mini Oscilloscope, normally it has a black background and the colors are a bit more fitting, but for posting online I usually invert the colors because I think the white background works better online, even though some of the colors do come out looking a little off :-)

Comment: There is an anomaly between the FET output voltages and pullup voltages, suggesting it's more than just a simple logic input. Perhaps it steals power from the signal or has a high current Schmitt trigger circuit. What is the device? _"this input port is bidirectional but configured for input."_ - how do you configure it for input, and what does the input signal do? What voltage do you get from the FET output with 5.1k when not connected to the device?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It's a data logger, the port is one of its digital bidirectional ports. What the manual says about the port is that it can be configured as SDI-12, UART, GPIO, or pulse counting up to 3 kHz; its digital input voltage is 3.3V and its output is 5V, and that it can supply 10mA at 3.5V; its absolute min/max input voltage is -10/+15V. I have it configured in software as UART Rx. The voltage at the output of the FET without the device is almost exactly 5V as expected.

Comment: What happens if you don't connect the drain of the TN2106 to the device? Do you get 0-5V swings or just 0-2V?

Comment: @ErikR Oh, strange: I just tested again and without the device connected I'm only measuring 0-2.5V, I thought previously that I had measured 0-5V, but I must have been mistaken. Sorry about that, I have to correct my above comment... I'll update the post too.

Comment: Couple of possibilities: the TN2106 is just not suitable for this application when driven at 3.3V; it also could be that the GPIO pin you are using is damaged. See if using a different GPIO pin makes any difference.

Comment: If the output is 0V (when the input is 3.3V) then the MOSFET is being driven hard enough. If the output is only 2V when the input is 0V then something is wrong with the MOSFET or GPIO pin.

Comment: @ErikR Thanks for prompting me to test further, see the answer I posted for the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **the MOSFET was bad.** After swapping it out, everything works.

Further testing showed that the input port of the device does act like it's just a 100kΩ pulldown. Both MOSFETs are suitable in the circuit, the ZVN4424A with the 1k pullup just provides better rise times and max voltage.

Thanks to everyone in the comments who pushed me to test further.